# Blueprint CXF serviceFactories: Need an instance per request

Tags: osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, aries

I am using Apache Karaf, CXF, and Aries Blueprint.

I have a bundle which defines a number of JAX-RS services. By default, CXF will make these services singletons, but this will not work for me. I need a new instance to handle each request.

Referencing the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html), I tried to create JAX-RS ServiceFactories which return new instances of the services. The documentation had examples for Spring and I tried to Blueprint equivalent.

```
<reference id="groupService" interface="org.ozoneplatform.owf.server.service.api.GroupService"/>
<bean id="groups" class="org.ozoneplatform.owf.server.rest.GroupController" scope="prototype">
    <property name="service" ref="groupService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="groupFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.blueprint.jaxrs.BlueprintResourceFactory">
    <property name="beanId" value="groups" />
</bean>
<jaxrs:server id="ozoneplatform_cxf_endpoint"  address="/owf">
<jaxrs:serviceFactories>
    <ref bean="groupFactory" />
</jaxrs:serviceFactories>
```

Blueprint fails to start giving the error

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: 
Error setting property: PropertyDescriptor <name: resourceProviders, getter: null, setter: [class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setResourceProviders(interface java.util.List)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define "blueprintContainer" property for BlueprintResourceFactory instance as:

```
<bean id="groupFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.blueprint.jaxrs.BlueprintResourceFactory">
    <property name="beanId" value="groups" />
    <property name="blueprintContainer" ref="blueprintContainer"/>
</bean>
```

Where ref="blueprintContainer" is a reference to top-level manager (see [121.11 Blueprint Container](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.blueprint.html#i2088582))